# /tmp messed up, even ls /tmp fails

Tags: linux, tmp

We are seeing a small cluster become unusable. Initially the same behavior was on a compute node, it is now occuring on the head node. I do not know if this is the underlying source, but for certain something is screwed up with the `/tmp` directory so even `ls /tmp` hangs and cannot be killed. (`/tmp` is under `/`, not nfs mounted, and I can see everything else, for instance `/var/log`, `/proc` etc.) Because so many daemons and running tasks expect to access `/tmp`, it makes sense to me this is a significant part of the problem.

A hard reboot solves the problem for a while, but that is not a long term cure.

Suggestions welcome, not simply to run "ls -ld /tmp &" which won't do more than ls ...

Note: when the problem occurs, /tmp is screwed up; otherwise (as now) it is fine:

```
[ldm@head ~]$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126      221G  143G   78G  65% /
[ldm@head ~]$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 12 root root 20480 Jan 26 08:45 /tmp
```

For reference:

```
uname -a
"Linux head.cluster 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 13 22:55:44 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
```

The problem is intermittent. It just reappeared on one of the compute nodes, with dmseg -H showing at the end:
[Feb 7 00:51] INFO: task kworker/4:2:20770 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  +0.007162] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  +0.008112] kworker/4:2     D ffff985b47709040     0 20770      2 
[  +0.007307] Workqueue: events xprt_rdma_connect_worker [rpcrdma]
[  +0.006210] Call Trace:
[  +0.002638]  [] schedule+0x29/0x70 
[  +0.005159]  [] schedule_timeout+0x221/0x2d0 
[  +0.006035]  [] ? mthca_modify_qp+0x8f/0x310 [ib_mthca] 
[  +0.006988]  [] wait_for_completion+0xfd/0x140 
[  +0.006204]  [] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20 
[  +0.005776]  [] __ib_drain_sq+0x181/0x1c0 [ib_core] 
[  +0.006638]  [] ? ib_sg_to_pages+0x1a0/0x1a0 [ib_core] 
[  +0.006902]  [] ib_drain_sq+0x25/0x30 [ib_core] 
[  +0.006292]  [] ib_drain_qp+0x12/0x30 [ib_core] 
[  +0.006291]  [] rpcrdma_ep_disconnect+0x58/0x150 [rpcrdma] 
[  +0.007244]  [] rpcrdma_ep_connect+0x139/0x400 [rpcrdma] 
[  +0.007073]  [] ? wake_up_atomic_t+0x30/0x30 
 
[  +0.006022]  [] xprt_rdma_connect_worker+0x33/0x60 [rpcrdma]
 
[  +0.007505]  [] process_one_work+0x17f/0x440 
[  +0.006022]  [] worker_thread+0x126/0x3c0 
[  +0.005765]  [] ? manage_workers.isra.25+0x2a0/0x2a0 
[  +0.006725]  [] kthread+0xd1/0xe0 
[  +0.005071]  [] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40 
[  +0.006285]  [] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin+0x21/0x21 
[  +0.006714]  [] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40 

ls -ld /tmp 
drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 169 Feb  7 11:28 /tmp 
ls -ld /boot 
dr-xr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 16 12:09 /boot 
ls -ld / hangs -- it seems that NFS mount(s) have died.

Comment: First thing I would try would be `ls -ld /tmp &`  to list the type of /tmp in the background. Having it in the background means even it it hangs you will still have your shell session. Second step would be to examine the mounts.

Comment: What's running on this cluster, and have any updates been performed lately? What is the OS and kernel version?

Comment: Run `ls -ld /tmp &` as directed; The `/etc/os-release` and `uname -a` are kind of irrelevant; it's not like there are a thousand different variants of Centos 7.

Comment: You might also want to run `dmesg -H` and see if the listing produced includes any error messages suggesting filesystem corruption or hardware issues. On CentOS 7, hanging processes may typically also produce messages in `dmesg` output once they've hung for more than two minutes or so, but those messages are not very interesting since you already know that `ls` processes are hanging.

Comment: When the problem occurs, /tmp is screwed up; otherwise (as now) it is fine:
df -h /tmpFilesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126      221G  143G   78G  65% /
ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 12 root root 20480 Jan 23 08:15 /tmp

Comment: Your `/tmp` is within the root filesystem, which is on `/dev/md126`, so it is some kind of a software RAID setup. Which RAID mode? What is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`? And `grep md126 /proc/mounts` also, please (need to verify the filesystem type and the **actual** rw/ro state of the filesystem).

Comment: When `/tmp` hangs, does `/` hang too? What about `ls -ld /tmp`? Have the NFS mounts you mentioned hung at this point? Specifically, is there a file on a hung NFS mount symlinked into `/tmp`?

Comment: You might also want to boot the system to rescue mode from external media, activate your RAID set, and then run the appropriate filesystem checking tool for the root filesystem on `/dev/md126`. NOTE: if the filesystem type is XFS, the traditional `fsck` or `fsck.xfs` will do **nothing**. You'll need to use `xfs_repair -n /dev/md126` to actually scan an XFS filesystem for errors. If errors are reported, run the command again without the `-n` option - but be aware that `xfs_repair` may not be as robust as the ext2/3/4 `fsck` tool you may be more familiar with.